# trouble in Group by query

Tags: mysql

todo：I grouped a set of data by c_id and took the data for the maximum value of the height of each group.
problem：The data that does not display the maximum value correctly like c_id=3 in picture no.2.
[image]
[image]

I want to ask how to fix it, thanks.

Comment: If performance is important, consider a solution along these lines: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/096589/1 Note the index on c_id, height - and for next time see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * 
  from student
 where (c_id, age,height) in ( Select c_id
                                    , max(age) age
                                    , max(height) as height 
                                 from student 
                                group 
                                   by c_id )
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @D.Todd if it helps please keep upvote and accept answer for SO appreciation

Comment: of course~~~~~~

Comment: @Strawberry seriously ????

Comment: @Strawberry http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aaf88f/2 this link only for you buddy and you did again down vote i really love your down vote :P

Comment: @Strawberry  i considered his sample data not yours

Comment: @Strawberry i don't know the OP's thought i see who's age greater his height also greater then why not i consider this can you explain that

Comment: OK, but it seems to that this solution is still nonsensical. What does it mean to return both the max height and max age? Plus, there is no reference to age in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can check this query out:

```
SELECT `id`, `name`, `gender`, `age`, `c_id`, MAX(`height`) AS height 
FROM `student` 
GROUP BY `c_id` 
ORDER BY `height` DESC;
```

Here is the [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cdee23/1)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: The values returned for id, name, gender, and age in this query are indeterminate. They may be correct, but only by luck. The manual covers this in considerable detail.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Select id, name, gender, age, c_id, height
From student
Where (c_id, age) in (Select c_id, max(age) from student group by c_id)
Order by height desc
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: To the best of my recollection, a solution like this cannot use an index.

Comment: Also, of what relevance is the max(age) !?!

Comment: @Strawberry in won't use index ?

Comment: @Strawberry hope you read the question fully. he want max age of student under each c_id with their details

Comment: Actually, it will. I stand corrected,

Comment: I read the question.

Comment: There are 6 rows in the table but in the expected output 4 rows only. That's they want max age in each c_id.

Comment: Actually, the OP hasn't provided a desired result.